# RavenDB : Keword Analyzer with .Search() command

Tags: ravendb

I am attempting to do a query in RavenDB using the `Search` method, but I am running into an issue in that it completely ignores the `KeywordAnalyzer` set up. So in a situation where I have ...

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

Trying to search for "Item 1" pulls up all three items, despite having set the analyzer on the name field to be the `KeywordAnalyzer`, like this ...

```
Map = items => from item in items
               select new Result {
                   Id = item.Id,
                   Name = item.Name
               };

Index(i => i.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
Analyze(n => n.Name, "KeywordAnalyzer");
```

At which point, I use the index like this;

```
var results = RavenSession
    .Query<Models.Items.Item, Indexes.Item__ByName>()
    .Customize(c => c.WaitForNonStaleResults())
    .Search(n => n.Name, name)
    .ToList();
```

My expectations are that when I search for "Item 1", I only get back "`Item 1`". Not all of the other items. But this just does not seem to be listening to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have 2 conflicting definitions:

```
Index(i => i.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
Analyze(n => n.Name, "KeywordAnalyzer");
```

The first tells it to use StandardAnalyzer, the second KeywordAnalyzer.

Remove the first line and you're set.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It still uses the various individual parts of the word.

Comment: The query works properly when done in the Raven administration interface; If I type in "1", it only pulls up `Item `'. But in the actual code running, with exactly what I showed you above, it still finds the other two items.

Comment: This, in itself, is an evidence that this field is not using KeywordAnalyzer. KeywordAnalyzer will not be able to find "Item 1" given "1" as a query.

Comment: I am going to try and make a failing test.

Comment: Hey there, I have produced a failing test, as promised: https://gist.github.com/ciel/141f2d70ede4dff55fe9

Comment: I'm pretty sure its caused by the fix to this bug: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-1526 . For now use `.Where(x => ..)` instead of search, and if you feel like it report this as a bug to the mailing list or the tracker.

Comment: I was under the understanding that search was not respective of how many documents you tried to pull, but "Where" only looked at the immediate ones that are taken; is this still true? There are situations where I need to try and find one or two documents when there are thousands more to search through than I can actually return in a single query.

Comment: The only difference between Where and Search is related to analysis of the text being used to query, they both will respect the query size operators the same.

Comment: Thank you, this answers a lot. I had avoided using `Where` because I was under the (incorrect) assumption that it only worked on the amount of results actually taken, where `Search` would go through all of the documents and then return up to the amount of results requested.

Comment: Though this confuses me; If `Where` does this, what is the purpose of `Search`?